# Create array in Smarty template

Tags: civicase, templates, smarty

I want to modify the  Smarty template sites/all/modules/civicrm/templates/CRM/Case/Audit/Report.tpl. I want to complement an existing foreach expression with comparing the incoming variable $group.title to an array of titles, and execute the following code only if the current $group.title is found in that array.

```
{assign var=visible-fields value=['value1, value2']}
<div> Visible fields var: {$visible-fields} </div>

{if $group.title|in_array:$visible-fields}
  <h2>{$group.title}</h2>
  <table class ="report-layout">
  {foreach from=$group.values item=row}
      <tr>
      <th class="label">{$row.label}</td>
      <td class="crm-case-report-custom-field">{$row.value}</td>
      </tr>
  {/foreach}
  </table>
{/if}
```

Now, I'm getting stuck on a rather simple task: The array `visible-fields` is not created. I have found some forum threads from the 2000s suggesting some expressions. I have tried the following, none of which seems to work:

- `{assign var=visible-fields value=['value1, value2']}`
- `{assign var=visible-fields value=['value1', 'value2']}`
- `{assign var='visible-fields' value=['value1, value2']}`
- and the same with "" instead of ''
- `{assign var="visible-fields" value=","|explode:['value1, value2']}`

Printing the variable with `<div> Visible fields var: {$visible-fields} </div>`  results in a 0.

I also tried solving the problem with a `{php}...{/php}` block, but then the web app throws an error. Maybe I have to enable the support for these inline php blocks somewhere, but before trying that, I want to try solving it with the Smarty expression, because creating an array shouldn't be so difficult, right?

Can somebody tell me how to do it, or post a link?

Comment: Did you try with an underscore instead of dash, i.e. `$visible_fields`? I don't think smarty variables can have dashes: https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method works for me:

```
{assign var=visible_fields value=','|explode:'value1,value2'}
<div>Visible fields var:
  {foreach from=$visible_fields item=foo}
    <div>Element is {$foo}</div>
  {/foreach}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It was really the dash that broke the code...